# Socket programming in Python -- actual remote port

Tags: python, sockets

I've been doing a bit of network programming these days in Python and would like to confirm the flow I think happens between the client and the server:

- The servers listens to a given
  advertised port (9999)
- The client connects to the server by creating a new socket (e.g. 1111)
- The servers accepts the client request and automatically spawns a new socket (????) which would now handle the communication between the client and the server

As you can see, in the above flow there are 3 sockets involved:

- The server socket which listens to clients
- The socket spawned by the client
- The socket spawned by the server to handle client

I'm aware of getting the ports for the first two sockets (9999 and 1111) but don't know how to get the "real" port which communicates with the client on the server side.The snippet I'm using right now is:

```
def sock_request(t):
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    s.connect(('localhost', 9999))
    print('local sock name: ' + str(s.getsockname()))
    print('peer sock name: ' + str(s.getpeername()))
    s.send('a' * 1024 * int(t))
    s.close()
```

Any help on getting the "port" number on the server which actually communicates with the client would be much appreciated. TIA.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The new socket is on the same port. A TCP connection is identified by 4 pieces of information: the source IP and port, and the destination IP and port. So the fact that your server has two sockets on the same port (i.e. the listening socket and the accepted socket) is not a problem.

Comment: Five pieces of information:  source address, source port, destination address, destination port, protocol.

Comment: Since we are talking about a TCP connection, the protocol is implied. At the IP level the protocol is distinguishing - that is, you can be using both TCP and UDP between the same local/remote address/port combo.

Comment: @dty: OK, so if I get this right, the four part tuple uniquely identifies each "TCP" packet? I've never done assembly or low level programming but doesn't having the same "port" communicate with the client *and* listen to new requests choke the port? Does this mean that my step 3 is wrong (server assigns a new socket for the client)?

Comment: You seem to be confusing sockets, connections, and ports.  dty is correct in that a server accepting a connection does not move that connection to a new port.  I suggest you read up on Berkely socket programming if you want a better understanding of what's going on under the covers.

Comment: I recommend Comer/Stevens, Internetworking with TCP/IP, Volumes 1-3. This particular stuff is covered in Volume 1, Chapter 12 of the editions on my bookshelf (Ed. 2).

Comment: @dty, @Forest: Please let me try it once again; "so basically after receiving a client request, the server creates a new Socket object (which has the same port number as the listening port). This isn't a problem as such since the connection between the client and the server is uniquely identified by the (src ip, src port, dst ip, dst port) tuple". Better?